# getting subdirectories from a directorie

Tags: delphi, subdirectory

I try to get the subdirectories of a directorie i have a working script but i only want the subdirectorie name and not the names of the directories before.

Example:
If i enter: "\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0"
Then this is my output now:
"\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\bin"
"\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\bin64"
"\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\binosx32"
...

But i want that my output is:
"bin"
"bin64"
"binosx32"
...

This is the script what i use now:

```
procedure GetSubDirectories(const directory : string; list : TStrings) ;
 var
   sr : TSearchRec;
 begin
   try
     if FindFirst(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(directory) + '*.*', faDirectory, sr) < 0 then
       Exit
     else
     repeat
       if ((sr.Attr and faDirectory <> 0) AND (sr.Name <> '.') AND (sr.Name <> '..')) then
         List.Add(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(directory) + sr.Name) ;
     until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
   finally
     SysUtils.FindClose(sr) ;
   end;
 end;
```

How can i make this script like in my example?

Comment: Use the IOUtils unit to avoid writing this code yourself

Comment: As David mentioned already, why you're not using http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory ?

Comment: @RBA I was looking for a system method that would do this for them given that FindFirst is deprecated, but I couldn't find anything in TPath that would return the last subdirectory of a path. :-(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
List.Add(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(directory) + sr.Name)
```

with

```
List.Add(sr.Name)
```

Comment: @RBA, time is relative.